# Electric scooter motor

Tags: brushless-motor

Can a 240w motor comfortably drive an electric scooter weighing net 56kg (gross weight c120kg) at 45km/hr? I don’t get clear answers when I ask dealerships about why one advertised scooter has a motor 2000w whilst another 240, when the scooter weight/speed spec is similar. Many thanks if you can enlighten me.

Comment: My guess, which is just a guess, is that it might be a bit tough. I can put out a bit more than 240W on a bike for quite a while, but I'd struggle to bike in 45km/h. A bike is likely to have less rolling friction and air resistance than a scooter as well.